# Navigation node description programmatically

Tags: navigation, spnavigationnode

How can we add navigation node description programmatically.

I have this code:

```
SPNavigationNode MyNav= new SPNavigationNode("Nav Text", "NavUrl", true);
MyNav.Update();               
currentNav.AddAsLast(MyNav);
```

The arguments only set the Title and the URL, but how do we set the description when we hover over the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tooltip using the `Properties` HashTable.

So in your case it will be

```
MyNav.Properties["Description"] = "Nav Text";
MyNav.Update();
```

Comment: that worked :S sorry.. I was lost in this